# How to show "No Text Here" from Rich Text Editor in Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor, richtext-editor

I am trying to show the `[No Text Here]` to Content Editors when there is not a value in that field (for example name of the field "Text") in Experience Editor so that they can edit the text in Experience Editor without going to Content Editor. Is there any way to achieve this?

Should I use the **Edit Frame Buttons** or is there a way to set a **default value** for that specific template that has that field?

Comment: You can set the default value for that field by going into the template standard value and mention your default text there for a particular field.

Comment: OOTB Sitecore shows "No text in field" in experience if you have an empty field in Sitecore. Do you want to change its text or it is not working for you? Also please provide your Sitecore version information

Comment: If you want to add a field name in "No Text in Field", then you can follow - https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/09/20/show-title-when-blank/

Answer (score 1):

When we do not have any value in the field in Content editor

[image]

it will show in Experience Editor like the below image :-

[image]

This is the default functionality in Sitecore.
You can edit the field value in Experience Editor, for this you need to add the below code in the view for the particular field.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Intro")
```

When you will add this code then in Experience editor you can add/edit data directly and after saving it, it will save in Content Editor.

Answer (score 0):

The one way to add `[No Text Here]` value in the template's standard value instead to add a condition in cshtml to apply `[No Text Here]` specifically for `Experience Editor` but make sure you add text in all fields where `[No Text Here]` value is coming otherwise on CD, `[No Text Here]` text will display. If this is not a condition then you can add condition in cshtml

[image]